# how I can set an extension method on the bool type that toggle it's value it like this, isSelected.toggle()?

Tags: dart

I knew about types and I knew that they are immutable such as String, bool...
my goal is to get the possibility to toggle a `bool` value like this :

```
   bool isSelected = true;
    isSelected.toggle();    
    // expect isSelected value to be false
```

well I asked before about this and I learned that types are immutable so I can only re-assign the value to the `bool` type

**But**, I feel that this can be done in some other way, but I don't know how.
can you share with me your ideas in some way?

Comment: This is not possible.  You instead should just do `isSelected = !isSelected`.

Comment: actually, I found a tricky way, using StreamController and Streams,for every call it add to stream the Random().nextBool() and return it

Comment: That's not really the same thing.  If you're willing to use something other than a `bool` directly, then you could simply create a class that wraps a `bool` member and have a `toggle()` method that inverts it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot work.

Extension methods work on values. You cannot toggle a *variable* by calling a method on its value, that only allows you to read the variable (to get the value).

You need `=` somewhere in order to actually change the variable.

Or you could wrap the boolean in an object:

```dart
class Bool {
  bool value;
  Bool(this.value);
  bool get isTrue => value;
  bool get isFalse => !value;
  bool get not => !value;
  bool toggle() => value = !value;
}
```

But that's another thing entirely.